# Android startActivity(galleryIntent, 0); got error here

Tags: android, android-intent

I have question with Intent, So I am doing select photo from gallery, I try to use    `startActivity(galleryIntent,0);` but always got error says Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'int', required: 'android.os.Bundle'

Here is my code

```
protected void showChoosePicDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Profile.this);
    builder.setTitle("Change Photo");
    String[] items = {"Gallery"};
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case CHOOSE_PICTURE:
                    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivity(galleryIntent, 0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try{
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            assert cursor != null;
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            userImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
            cursor.close();

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't pick Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I m being stupid here instead of `startActivity(galleryIntent,0);` it sure be `startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0);`